# Why does this socket reader code end up with buffer truncations?

Tags: scala, sockets

For a tcp-bound server socket we are reading it as follows:

```
   val BufSize = (Math.pow(2, 20) - 1).toInt  // Far more than necessary
    val is = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream)
    val os = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream)
    val buf = new Array[Byte](BufSize)
    val nread = is.read(buf)
    println(s"Nread=$nread")
```

We are seeing the `nread` as values under 2K even for for buffers that are up to 100K in length.  When the actual data sent is <  about 2K then the transfer succeeds: but naturally for anything larger we have EOFs:

```
[WARNING]
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:3063)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1914)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1529)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at org.openchai.tcp.util.TcpCommon$.deserializeObject(TcpCommon.scala:43)
    at org.openchai.tcp.util.TcpCommon$.deserializeStream(TcpCommon.scala:32)
    at org.openchai.tcp.util.TcpCommon$.unpack(TcpCommon.scala:54)
    at org.openchai.tcp.rpc.TcpServer$$anon$2.run(TcpServer.scala:112)
```

Given the `BufSize` is 1Megabyte why would we end up with issues here?

Note: if the `read` were put into a loop then on the second iteration it simply hangs.  Here is that attempted code:

```
   var nread = -1
    var totalRead = 0
    var off = 0
    do {
      if (!msgPrinted) {
        debug("Listening for messages.."); msgPrinted = true
      }
      do {
        println("about to read..")
        nread = is.read(buf,off, buf.length-off)
        totalRead += nread
        println(s"read $nread bytes (totalRead=$totalRead)")
      } while (nread > 0)
      println(s"Final off=$off bytes=$totalRead")
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that `read` will read exactly the requested number of bytes in one go.

Comment: @n.m.  Updated the OP: putting `read` in a loop results in a hang on the second invocation.

Comment: Please, add cycle condition.

Comment: @Zernike  the loop code was added to OP

Comment: I'm sorry. You are using BufferedInputStream which does the looping internally, so you don't have to. Please disregard my first comment. There must be some other reason.

Comment: It's strange. Error tells about deserialization via ObjectInputStream. Your code sample is different. Nothing can throw EOFException.